# ASP.NET MVC 3 localization: Resources for data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, resources, localization

We use ASP.NET MVC 3 and Entity Framework 4 and annotate our entities with attributes like [Required]. The validation works correct and an error message "The xxx field is required" is displayed. We try to localize our application. I used the Web Platform Installer and installed the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update Language Packs Installer and also installed the AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup_DEU.exe from the Microsoft Download page. But I still don't get german error messags. The rest of the application localizes properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the resources. They are in the full language pack of the .NET Framework 4 which has to be installed.